# Is there a frequency comparator device?

Tags: comparator

Is there a comparatorlike IC device which compares input frequency with a threshold frequency? I want to make a circuit which monitors input pulse train and whenever it is more than a set frequency the LED will be ON.

I dont want to use a microcontroller. 
And 5% accuracy is fine.

Comment: [Phase Frequency detector](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB828GB828&q=phase+frequency+detector&tbm=isch&source=univ&safe=strict&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrtoiXz-HiAhVHTxUIHXiDBXEQsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1565&bih=924)

Comment: A gated counter perhaps

Comment: Must the circuit decide after just one cycle of input? Or will you allow 10 cycles? or 1,000 cycles? and how much residual noise and trash and edge timing jitter is also imposed on the signal?

Comment: Asked a more specific question here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443042/frequency-comparator-circuit-in-ltspice-not-outputting-expected-state

Answer (score 4):

A retriggerable one-shot set to the pulse width of threshold frequency period will stay active ON. Then any interruption greater than this period will time out.  If you want a smoother operation, a LPF on this output will delay f>set f and filter out a 1 or more cycle dropout.

This can be achieved with a 1/2 dual ‘HC123 IC very easily. a Pot and series R with cap can tune to <1% if large tolerance parts are used and is very stable with Vdd and temp.

Using two of them you could choose 2 frequencies like +/- 10% if that was useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sunnyskyguy has a good answer which I can add this: the one-shot output can be used to switch a reference voltage on and off, and your switched waveform can be made to any accuracy required. Make sure the off state is low impedance to ground. Your input should be squared up to a rectangular pulse train to trigger the one-shot. The filtered output and a refernce voltage are then fed to a comparator. Of coursed the filtered output will have some ripple and this must be taken into account in your accuracy spec.

Comment: I assumed that the pulse train was logic level impedance and voltage so no signal conditioning is needed, but one input is Schmitt so that can be used to eliminate some noise.

Answer (score 2):

Go analog. Use a high-pass filter (capacitor and resistor) followed by an envelope detector (capacitor and diode) followed by a comparator.

Comment: I doubt that that method will yield 10% accurate results, whereas the monostable or missing-pulse detector can meet 2% accuracy over time and temperature with no trimming and a very good capacitor, and be adjusted to under 1%.  Plus, it has no envelope-detector lag; it is true cycle-by-cycle monitoring.

Comment: @AnalogKid this method could achieve the 5% accuracy OP mentioned. 1 or 2% is not needed, as per the question

Comment: My point was that 2% accuracy can be achieved with off-the-shelf, inexpensive components, so the 5% target can be maintained over a production run with no calibration adjustments.  I don't think a slope detector can do that.

Comment: Asked a more specific question here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443042/frequency-comparator-circuit-in-ltspice-not-outputting-expected-state

Comment: The analog method would introduce errors from variations in duty cycle. NG.