# Frequency comparator circuit in LTspice not outputting expected state

Tags: frequency, ltspice

I'm trying to simulate the circuit in the method shown [here](https://pe2bz.philpem.me.uk/Power/-%20Pulse/P-106-FreqCompare/cir10.htm) in LTspice as:

[image]

I use the same parts 74HCT74 and 74HCT00.

But the circuit does not function. Here I set F2>F1 and the outputs at R1 and R2 alwyas zero. I tried the swap the F1 and F2 nothing changes. I couldnt figure out what can be the problem here.

I uploaded the above circuit in LTspice [here](https://gofile.io/?c=ooGV1L) along with the 74HCT library and symbols as rar file.

Comment: Try a larger logic-level pulse, for example **PULSE(0 5 0 10n 10n 0.002 0.004)**

Comment: As @glen_geek mentions, your custom digital libraries show a 5V supply, but you're only supplying them with a 1V pulse. For those input sources to work, you'd have to be using the builtin A-devices `dflop` and `and` (with a proper `td` set for `dflop`s).

Comment: With 74HCT’ parts you need at <0.8,  >2.0 for “0,1” for valid logic levels and not to exceed either rail by 0.2V. The difference frequency will be reduced by slew rate of 25mV/ms = dV/dt=Vdd/2RC

Comment: You have only build the first part of a PFD (phase frequency discriminator), the output, as you seem to use it, will not work as a difference. The outputs have to be interpreted as an "up" and "down" signal, which need to be integrated. You need at least two output transistors as switches to be controlled by this signals, which then feed an R-C element (with separate R's for each path) or need to use two switchable current sources, as it is commonly done (there are issues with the voltage switches, which you can find in any good PLL book).